# Intermittent HibernateSystemException using gorm findAllBy

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, hibernate-4.x

What is the cause of this error?

> **...hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: collection is not associated with any session**

We are running into this error intermittently on our Grails app servers. We run the same request to the server 10 times with the same inputs (it's a read-only request), and maybe 5 out of 10 requests generate this error.

The client code that generates the error looks like this:

`def list = ParentData.findAllByGroupPartyIdAndCaseStatusIlike(groupPartyId, caseStatus)`

This is the first database call that happens in this request. The service method is marked `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`.

We were thinking at first that it was a data-specific issue having to do with our GORM mapping declarations, but it seems like even if there is no record with the specified groupPartyId and caseStatus, we still run into this error.

We can't step through the framework code in the debugger, because we can't reproduce the issue on our development servers.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: collection is not associated with any session; 
nested exception is
org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:101)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.MyService.$tt__getUpdate(MyService.groovy:...)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.MyController.getUpdate(MyController.groovy:...)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session
```

P.S. The app is running Grails 2.3.11, with the hibernate 4 plugin.

**Update**

We found that restarting the app seems to have fixed the issue, but we are still baffled about the root cause. Our working theory is that it's some kind of caching or DBCP issue.

Comment: Are you running into this bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2862

Comment: @LalitAgarwal: Thanks for the comment! I noticed that issue in the JIRA, but I had a hard time understanding the description. What does it mean for two entities to reference the same collection? Anyway, I can't fathom how a query that returns no results could produce that issue, or why the issue would be intermittent in nature. Any ideas?